# Proving equivalence of operators imply equivalence of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $A:L^2([0,1],\mu)\to L^2([0,1],\nu)$ an unitary operator. Prove that $$d\mu=\rho(x) d\nu$$ for some $L^1(\mu) \ni \rho(x) >0 (\mu\text{ a.e})$

I thought maybe saying $$\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|^2d\mu=\int_{[0,1]}|Af(x)|^2d\nu=\int_{[0,1]}|f|^2\cdot \frac{|A(f)|^2}{|f|^2}d\nu.$$ But for $f\in L^2([0,1],\nu)$ which is zero on a set with positive measure, it cannot be established.

How can I find that $\nu\ll \mu$  with positive derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current statement is also false. Consider uniform probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on the intervals $[0,\frac13]$ and $[\frac23,1]$ respectively. Consider the operator $A$ that shifts every function class in $L^2[0,\frac13]$ by adding $\frac23$ to its argument. It is easy to verify that this shift operation preserves the inner product, i.e., $A$ is unitary. Yet there cannot exist a function $\rho$ with the required properties, because $\rho(x)d\nu$ remains concentrated on the interval $[\frac23,1]$ whatever values $\rho$ takes.

Answer (score 1):

If absolute continuity is not given then the statement is false. As an example, take finite measures $\mu$ concentrated in ${0}$ and $\nu$ concentrated in ${1}.$ The $L^2$ spaces are one-dimensional and a unitary operator is easily constructed.

Comment: And if they were absolute continuous?

Comment: Also I fixed my requirement from $\rho$. The example in your answer now can't b applied.

Comment: (This answer was posted before absolute continuity became a hypothesis). @John D: I mean, absolute continuity with respect to each other. Absolute continuity w.r.t. Lebesgue measure is still insufficient because I can spread my measures uniformly over the intervals $[0,1/3]$ and $[2/3,1]$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but what if $\rho>0$ except on a set $E$ with $\mu(E)=0$?

Comment: You can't use properties of $\rho$ as a *hypothesis* if the assignment is to prove that a $\rho$ satisfying certain conditions exists.

Comment: What do you mean? I simply had typo while asking the question...

Comment: The question has changed fundamentally several times, so I will try to treat the latest version in a separate answer.